# MBP SSD impending failure

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, macos

Configuration:

- Late 2014 MBPr - Loaded (1TB SSD, etc.)
- Mavericks
- Bootcamp with Win7
- Paragon NTFS driver

I think my SSD may be failing. Recently, some files have started to go missing.

Specifically, I'll add a new file to an Xcode project, and things seem to work fine for the most part. Occasionally, Xcode gets in a mood where it is constantly saying that a specific file has been modified outside of the environment by another application - even when nothing else is running.

When rebooting, or waking up, the new file tends to be either corrupt, unreadable (with a "input/output error" message in terminal) or completely missing.

If I reboot into Win7 - Bootcamp, not a VM - and try to read the file - from an NTFS volume - the file will show up in a directory listing (command line). If I try to `cat` the file, I'll get a "The file does not exist" message. After that, the file no longer appears in the directory listing.

If I then reboot into OSX, the file will also be missing from the directory listing.

This seems to be happening more and more frequently lately.

I've tried removing the Paragon NTFS driver. I still get read errors on some files.

I suspect that the SSD is failing. Is there any cheap / free, reliable SSD diagnositic tool available that runs under OSX? I'd rather not have Apple send this thing off for repair for a week as I need the machine to do my job.

Help!

Answer (score 1):

There is an app named [DriveDx](http://binaryfruit.com/drivedx) that can show you if there are problems with the drive. Not that it is 100% full proof but better than nothing.

Also I remember I had issues with Paragon NTFS too (like file system corruption). Microsoft changes NTFS with each release and it is not "open source", so it is not known how compatible Paragon is. I am sure they do their best but it is difficult to be compatible with such closed system as NTFS.

Comment: Thanks - I'll check out DriveDx. I tried removing Paragon for a few days, didn't really have any effect. :/ Time to back it up and head to the Apple Store. Yay.